# How to one-way process html data for the view in CKEditor 5?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

In the CKEditor view for authors I need to change links to files so that the session ID of the author gets attached. However in the actual content for normal users the specific user ID is added automatically. Therefore the authors ID must not be saved in the content the author edits with CKEditor, it just has to be there in the view while he edits so that he can see an image for example. On save the 'clean' link without any IDs need to be saved.

In CKEditor 5 there seem to be more possibilities to achieve such a one-way data filtering for example with

- [Conversions](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_conversion-Conversion.html)
- the [Editing Engine](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/editing-engine.html) generally
- the [HtmlDataProcessor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_dataprocessor_htmldataprocessor-HtmlDataProcessor.html) specifically

However I couldn't find a good example respectively an easy and clean approach to achieve this. (My tries turned out to become quite complicated and didn't work properly...) I'd guess this is a quite common use case so maybe I'm overlooking something. Is there a good solution to this?

**Update 1:**
 Example links would be:

- "clean link" how it has to be saved but will never work:
  https://example.com/some-image.png
- modified link for specific users in content (and how it has to be modified in ckeditor view for authors as well):
   https://example.com/some-image.png?sessionId=currentUsersSessionId

**Update 2:**
While I was working further with CKEditor I came across more things like this which simply are very unpleasant from a developers point of view. And it seems this is by design, since quote from a Contributor 'fredck':

> [...] we want to bring the editor out of the "HTML Editor" thing, making it the perfect soluting for "quality content writing".

Implicitly this means, if you are a developer and you have advanced users with advanced use cases (which may be likely the case if you are on Stackoverflow) you are not the target audience and shouldn't use CKEditor in the first place.

You can read more about this for example in the discussion here (also it is about another feature): https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/592

Comment: Could you provide a short snippet what the links should look like for authors and for users?

Comment: I updated my question with some example links. However for me personally this hasn't high priority anymore since I ditched CKEditor meanwhile for other reasons (see my second update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify downloaded links you can write a custom downcast converter, which modifies obtained `href`.
Here is a working sample which adds the current timestamp to URLs:
https://codepen.io/msamsel/pen/zVMvZN?editors=1010

```
editor.conversion.for( 'dataDowncast' ).add( dispatcher => {
    dispatcher.on(
        'attribute:linkHref',
        ( evt, data, conversionApi ) => {
            if ( !conversionApi.consumable.test( data.item, 'attribute:linkHref' ) ) {
                return;
            }

            if ( data.attributeNewValue ) {
                data.attributeNewValue += `#time=${ ( new Date() ).getTime() }`;
            }
        },
        { priority: 'high' }
    );
} );
```

Few words how it works.
There is created listener which reacts on `attribute:linkHref` changes (it's fired only when data are obtained anyway because it's `dataDowncast`). Listeners fires with `'high'` priority to change URL before the actual Link plugin will create an output. First is checked if the given model element is not consumed, but without consuming it, because we want to preserve native behavior which will process this same element again. The attribute value is extended with a timestamp, what finish this listener. After that, the native behaviour is fired, which has `'normal'` priority.

A similar approach was used to implement [custom link attributes](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/link.html#custom-link-attributes-decorators). More about dispatcher and conversion process might be found here:

- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/editing-engine.html#conversion
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_downcastdispatcher-DowncastDispatcher.html